# Rails - Not being able to create an instance even after adding foreign key

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord

I am creating the following tables in Rails (with Postgresql):

- `User`: a user can be in one or more groups and can be the owner of one or more groups
- `Group`: a group has an admin (which is one of the users) and one or more users
- `Participant`: a participant the table in between the other two to connect them

The models are like this:

```
#User.rb

class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :groups
  has_many :participants
end
```

```
#Group.rb

class Group < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :participants
end
```

```
#Participant.rb

class Participant < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :group
  belongs_to :user
end
```

After this, I did some migration to change the name of the `user_id` that the `Group` would have, into `admin_id`:

```
class ChangeForeignKeyForGroups < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.1]
  def change
    rename_column :groups, :user_id, :admin_id
  end
end
```

So now, my `schema` looks like this:

```
  create_table "groups", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.text "description"
    t.integer "participants"
    t.bigint "admin_id", null: false
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.index ["admin_id"], name: "index_groups_on_admin_id"
  end

  create_table "participants", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.bigint "group_id", null: false
    t.bigint "user_id", null: false
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.index ["group_id"], name: "index_participants_on_group_id"
    t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_participants_on_user_id"
  end

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "email", default: "", null: false
    t.string "encrypted_password", default: "", null: false
    t.string "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.string "username"
    t.index ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true
    t.index ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_users_on_reset_password_token", unique: true
```

The problem is that once I try to create a Group in seeds, I keep having this error:

```
pry(main)> group = Group.new(name: "Test Group", description: "blablabal")
=> #<Group:0x00007fdbcdd03f80 id: nil, name: "Test Group", description: "blablabal", participants: nil, admin_id: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
[5] pry(main)> group.valid?
=> false
[6] pry(main)> group.errors
=> #<ActiveModel::Errors:0x00007fdbcdc7ad98
 @base=#<Group:0x00007fdbcdd03f80 id: nil, name: "Test Group", description: "blablabal", participants: nil, admin_id: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>,
 @errors=[#<ActiveModel::Error attribute=user, type=blank, options={:message=>:required}>]>
```

It seems I am missing the `user`, so I try adding it but it throws the same error:

```
user = User.first
  User Load (1.4ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1]]
=> #<User id: 7, email: "jose@test.io", created_at: "2022-05-31 10:29:06.208673000 +0000", updated_at: "2022-05-31 10:29:06.208673000 +0000", username: "Jose">

pry(main)> group = Group.new(name: "Test Group", description: "blablabal", admin_id: user.id)
=> #<Group:0x00007fdbdd205ad8 id: nil, name: "Test Group", description: "blablabal", participants: nil, admin_id: 7, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
[13] pry(main)> group.valid?
=> false
[14] pry(main)> group.errors
=> #<ActiveModel::Errors:0x00007fdbdd1d4578
 @base=#<Group:0x00007fdbdd205ad8 id: nil, name: "Test Group", description: "blablabal", participants: nil, admin_id: 7, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>,
 @errors=[#<ActiveModel::Error attribute=user, type=blank, options={:message=>:required}>]>
```

Am I doing something wrong? Have I structure it wrongly? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply renamed your foreign key but there's more to it that that. In my migration, I would have done something like this:

```
class ChangeForeignKeyForGroups < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.1]
  def change
    remove_reference :groups, :user, foreign_key: true
    add_reference :groups, :admin, foreign_key: true
  end
end
```

Mind you, I think the way you did the rename, it probably changes the index and foreign key as well. So you probably don't need to change it.

Then in your `group.rb` model you need to change the association:

```
belongs_to :admin, class_name: "User", foreign_key: :admin_id
```

Then if you go back to your seeds, you can change your group creation to this:

```
Group.new(name: "Test Group", description: "blablabal", admin: user)
```

Comment: Thanks!! I didn't do the `migration` part, just added the `group.rb` and it works like a charm!

Answer (score 1):

Ruby on Rails has certain naming conventions for associations between models. I suggest reading about [Active Record Associations
in the official Rais Guides](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html).

For example, if there is a `belongs_to :user` association in a `Group` model then Rails expects that there is a `user_id` column on the `groups` table in the database pointing to the `id` of a record in a table named `users`.

This allows Ruby on Rails to work without much configuration and it is called [convention over configuration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convention_over_configuration).

If you do not want to follow these conventions then you need to configure everything that doesn't follow this convention. In your example, you would need to add `foreign_key: 'admin_id'` to both sides of the association to tell Ruby on Rails that you do not want to use the default column naming but `admin_id` instead, like this:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :participants, foreign_key: 'admin_id'
  # ...

class Group < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user, foreign_key: 'admin_id'
  # ...
```

Because of the additional configuration needed in the case of non-default naming I highly suggest not using custom table names or foreign key names. And only use them when the database schema is not under your control. Therefore I suggest reverting the renaming from `user_id` to `admin_id`.